# Как корректно вывести результат SQL запроса в поле Edit?

Tags: sql, delphi

Необходимо посчитать количество записей в таблице между двумя датами заданными пользователем. и вывести в поле Edit.

```
DM->ADOQueryWork->SQL->Text =
            "Select count(*) from sale where sale.date  between  '" + DateTimePicker1->Date + "' and   '" +DateTimePicker2->Date+"';";    // вот сам запрос
        Edit1->Text=DM->ADOQueryWork->Fields->Fields[0]->AsString;
```

При таком раскладе выдает ошибку "Access Violation." Правильно ли я присваиваю результат запроса в едит? немного запутался с свойствами AdoQuery. или ошибка скорее всего связана с базой данных?

Answer (score 0):

1. Код похож на C++ Builder. Я с ним почти не работал, так что прошу прощения за возможные ошибки.
2. После указания запроса открыть Query не забыл?
   `DM->ADOQueryWork->Open()` или `DM->ADOQueryWork->Active = True`
3. В запросе лучше использовать параметры:

`"Select count(*) from sale where sale.date between :date1 and :date2";`

И потом указывать их:

`DM->ADOQueryWork->Parameters[ 0 ]->Value = ...`